# Merging two lines into one - Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a line like this

```
assignee: Akebono Brake Industry Co. Ltd.  , 
 Fujitsu Limited  application_no: 06/946,825
```

I want the output to be

```
assignee: Akebono Brake Industry Co. Ltd.  , Fujitsu Limited  
application_no: 06/946,825
```

To bring the **application_no: 06/946,825** to the next line, I can find **application_no:** and replace it with **\napplication_no:** in my NOTEPAD++

But, how can I bring that string that spans to next line back to the first line? I mean what should I do to get the **Fujitsu Limited** to the line starting with **assignee:**

Any guidance please?

Comment: Does the line break occur after the comma?

Comment: Yes it does. In all the occurrences of such pattern, the line break occurs only after a comma. The new line starts with a space in all such occurrences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Extended is the only mode that handles the newlines correctly but you need to match with regular expressions, you will need to do this in two steps.

First, use a regex find and replace to add some recognizable token to the beginning of each line you want to move up, I used 'MATCH' but you could definitely change this.

[image: Step 1: Add a token to beginning of matching lines]

Then, switch to Extended to search for a newline followed by the token, and replace it with an empty string to delete both the line break and the token.

[image: Step 2: Use the token to remove the line break]

Comment: that'll only work for a row that starts with 'Fujitsu Limited' not so generic.

Comment: OP didn't specify any generic pattern he wants to perform the substitution for.

Comment: That is my fault. I should have mentioned. The one I gave was just an example. Actually I have similar patterns in a file with more than 10million records. I need to find all occurrences of **^[ ][A-Z]** (that is lines starting with a space followed by a capitalized alphabet) and merge that whole line with the line just before it.

Comment: @BhavaniKannan - See my edit, it takes two steps but should do what you want.

Comment: @F.J - Fantastic! Simple yet works like a treat! Now, why did I not think of it? I lack some very basic common sense :-/

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution. One step:

Search:

```
(^.*,.*$)\r\n([ A-Z]*[ ])
```

Replace:

```
\1\2\r\n
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with notepad++, but surely there is a "/n" after the comma? Could you not just remove the char that creates the new line segment? ie: the inverse of what you are doing to application_no:

Comment: I did try this. It remove the new line break but does not help me take (append) this new line back to the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with regular expressions due to a flaw in the Scintilla engine which Notepad++ uses. However, it works in *"extended"* find mode, so use that. Search for `,\r\n` and replace with `,`.

Change the `\r\n` to only `\n` on Linux, or to only `\r` on Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

I've just wrote that macro and works with your example.
Add this macro into shortcuts.xml, if you are using win7 file is located at C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++

Just open your text file and get cursor to firts line, then run this macro.

```
<Macro name="stackoverflow" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="application_no" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2302" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2451" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2306" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2326" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="application_no" />
    <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
    <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1" sParam="" />
    <Action type="0" message="2308" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
    <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&#x000D;" />
    <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&#x000A;" />
</Macro>
```