# How to combine specific Lines together

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to combine Lines together when i have regular format:

```
Input:      
4446351
Output: 
kkmeshla
```

and need:

```
4446351|kkmeshla
```

Comment: Delete input output lines using delete button, and then separate with |. If this is what you are trying to do. Can you make the question clear if possible?

Comment: yes but than literal is behind Line1 and Line 2. I need all in one Line

Comment: Are you trying to write some code for this or just trying to write something in notepad++ ??

Comment: try something in notepad++

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811053/merging-two-lines-into-one-notepad may be this would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `Input:\s*\R(.+)\ROutput:\s*\R`
Replace with: `$1|`

`Regular expression`  must be checked.

`\R` stands for any line break, ie. `\n` or `\r` or `\n\r`

Comment: very cute regex way. Thank you:)