# combine two lines into one with special condition in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

i need to conevert line like this

```
[
"country": "AD",
"name": "Sant Julià de Lòria",
"country": "BE",
"name": "Pas de la Casa",
"country": "IT",
"name": "Ordino",
"country": "AD",
"name": "les Escaldes",
"country": "IE",
"name": "Callan",
"country": "AE",
"name": "Abu Dhabi",
...
]
```

into this:

```
"name": "Sant Julià de Lòria, AD",
"name": "Pas de la Casa, BE",
"name": "Ordino, IT",
"name": "les Escaldes, AD",
```

i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811053/merging-two-lines-into-one-notepad) but no success. thank you for your time.

Comment: You could match `"country":\h+"([^"]+)",\R("name":\h+"[^"]+)(",)` and replace with `$2, $1$3` See https://regex101.com/r/hpjstl/1

Comment: i used find and replace (ctrl+f), but it said cant find the text "...". serach mode-> regular expression

Comment: Do all the lines start at the beginning of the string or is there something before or after it?

Comment: [ at the beginning and ] at the end. so i just need to get rid if them?

Comment: If you use  `ctrl+h` to get the replace tab, then using the pattern you should be able to find the matches and use `$2, $1$3` in the replacement. I am using notepad 7.7.1 You mean like **["country": "AD",]**

Comment: i got this text "0 occurrences were replaced." im using v7.8.5. btw its json file i forgot to mention

Comment: Can you update the text in the question with the exact text you are using in notepad? The pattern now works for https://regex101.com/r/hpjstl/1

Comment: i updated the text, but pretty much looks the same. its a long list

Comment: It should still work, see https://imgur.com/a/FWj9ztw

Comment: nvm it worked!! i restart the notepad and it worked. thank you so much

Comment: I added the screenshots with the initial data (without the brackets but it still works) to an answer so you can see the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you are referring to uses a single capturing group and you could use `\R` to match a unicode newline sequence.

**Find what**

```
"country":\h+"([^"]+)",\R("name":\h+"[^"]+)(",)
```

**Replace with:**

```
$2, $1$3
```

Check *Wrap around*, enable *Regular expression* and click *Replace All*

Result

```
"name": "Sant Julià de Lòria, AD",
"name": "Pas de la Casa, BE",
"name": "Ordino, IT",
"name": "les Escaldes, AD",
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: it worked!! i think my notepad got messed up, it worked after i open a new window